# Python socket server send remote commands

Tags: python, sockets, server, python-cmd

Right now, I'm trying to make a socket server in Python that takes input from a client, processes it, does whatever is need to be done, and then sends a message back to the client showing that it's done.

The problem I am having right now is that the system can't recognize a command that is sent by the client. I am currently using an `if` statement to compare strings. The data received is decoded into UTF-8. I don't see why the `if` statement can't compare them.

```
'''
    Simple socket server using threads
'''

import socket
import sys
from thread import *
import cmd

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        databyte = conn.recv(1024)
        reply = 'OK...' + data
        data = databyte.decode('utf-8')
        if data == 'light'
            print 'light'
        if not data: 
            break

        conn.sendall(reply)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Code formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Others can also fix the formatting, so it's okay if you don't get it right the first time.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the guide. I have now fixed the formatting.

Comment: What do you send, and what does your code receive?

Comment: I send some text and the code receives it to check if it is a command. If it is, then I will do whatever the command is supposed to do.

Comment: Try printing the length of data after you receive it. It may contain non-printable chars and that would explain why your comparison doesn't evaluate true.